# Gmail LodgingReservation Markup showing incorrect dates

Tags: gmail, schema.org

I am managing a hotel, and sending confirmation emails to clients.

Gmail started showing the hotel reservation markup on these email (although I didn't add the schema).

I got 2 problems:

1. even without the schema, when message is in English, google shows correct dates, and in hebrew it doesn't:

[this is my English confirmation email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiToD.png), which gmail understands correctly and shows Feb-1 until Feb-2

[this is my Hebrew confirmation email **of the same reservation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWH9j.png), which gmail understands incorrectly as Feb-1 until Feb-3 [this is a screenshot of the markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d05g3.png)

2. so in order to solve it I used gogle's guide and implemented the schema with all the data.
   this is the schema I am sending (under the `<head>` section):

I also made sure I have correct SPF and DKIM records for my domain

```json
<script type="application/ld+json">


{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "LodgingReservation",
        "reservationNumber": "39180",
        "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
        "modifiedTime": "2020-05-25T16:27:21+02:00",
        "underName": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "David Test"
        },
        "reservationFor": {
          "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
            "name": "RubyTel Aviv",
            "image": "https://www.tellavista.com/assets/flats/524/e5b62830_thumbnail.jpg",
            "url": "https://rubytelaviv.com",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "Yehuda ha-Levi Street 11",
            "addressLocality": "Tel Aviv",
            "addressRegion": "Tel Aviv",
            "postalCode": "Ruby Tel Aviv",
            "addressCountry": "Israel"
          },
          "telephone": "0545-808680"
        },
        "price": "770",
        "priceCurrency": "ILS",
        "checkinDate": "2021-02-01T14:00:00+01:00", 
        "checkoutDate": "2021-02-02T12:00:00+01:00",
        "lodgingUnitDescription": "Ruby X - Standard Double bed (Room 10)",
        "numAdults" : "2",
        "numChildren" : "0"
}

</script>
```

**Gmail just ignores this code, I don't even see it when I inspect the email**

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have you validated your email using the markup tester https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/ ?

Have you registred with google using https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google ?